# How to access data inside a Vuex array when Proxied?

Tags: vue.js

I have an array in Vuex. When I render the data to the DOM with a v-for directive it works fine. But if I try to access it in any other way, like:

```
mounted() {
   console.log(this.$store.state.myArray[0].property1)
}
```

I get an error, the property1 can't be read.

If I console.log the whole array, I get undefined.

I have read on other posts that the Proxy system in Vue does not alter the normal array behaviour, but then how come I can't access the array data other than with v-for?

Thanks!

Comment: "If I console.log the whole array, I get undefined." - this is unlikely, because " property1 can't be read" means that it's empty array. Please, don't retell errors and messages but post them as is. The question doesn't make sense without https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown what's the counterpart with v-for you're describing. v-for obviously doesn't iterate over empty arrays, and it won't cause an error in case a non-array was provided, so it doesn't need `v-if="arr" v-for="el in arr"`

Comment: Thanks, this was a good tip as when I started to write a reproductible example, I realised my mistake. The component was mounted before the array was assigned any data. So v-for worked as it is reactive, but the mounted hook is obviously not.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question as I realised my mistake when trying to write a more reproductible example. It was a simple synchronisation issue. The component was loaded before the array was assigned any data. So v-for worked as it is reactive. But accessing the array in the mounted hook failed because when the componented mounted, there was no data in the array yet.